# how can I add a parameter to a route in the controller's action method

Tags: url, parameters, action

In a Controller action method I have a variable `$message` ,how can I pass the message to the redirect url.

```
$message = 11;

if(!$success){
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myroute'); // how can I add $message paramter here??
   //I change it to  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('myroute',array(message=>$message)); it seams that it does't work 
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would tag this with the language you're using, and the application if possible.  A short description of what you're trying to do would help too.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use `toUrl()`  method

```
return this->redirect()->toUrl(this->url('someRoute').'?messsage='.$message)
```